# WAMPSERVER php_memcache extension

Tags: php, memcached, php-extension

I have a copy of `php_memcache.dll` (from [php_memcache-2.2.6-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/)) which I have placed in my `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\ext` folder.

In WAMP I can see `php_memcache` in my extensions list, however whenever I start the extension I get the following warning:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
>   library
>   'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/ext/php_memcache.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.

This does not happen for any other extension that I can turn on or off.

Have tried moving `php_memcache.dll` to `C:\windows\system32` but makes no difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your extension probably not fit the compilation mode of wampserver.
Is it compiled with vc9 (visual 2008) and a non threads safe support ?

My wampserver (latest available) is compiled in VC6 TS.
To know this info check phpinfo() on line :

- Compiler
- Thread safety

Comment: Compiler is MSVC6 (Visual C++ 6.0) and Thread Safety enabled?

Comment: So you should use an extension compiled with same charac.PHP compiled in VC6 & TS , all the extension must have been compiled in same way in order to work together.

Comment: How do I find this? The only dll I can find is for the version I am using?!

Comment: Found the old dll - http://shikii.net/blog/installing-memcached-for-php-5-3-on-windows-7/

Comment: Maybe try this one : http://shikii.net/blog/downloads/php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-VC6-x86.zip. I'm too slow ^^

Comment: It took my 7 different files to find the right version of that dll.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying other versions of the dll.

2.2.5.0 works for me using WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

The VC9 builds are the only supported builds. VC6 (which is used as convenience builds by Apache) is not supported anymore.

Latest PHP version (and PELC extensions) are only available as VC9 builds. Xamp are already moving their suite to VC9, other already did. You can also do it yourself using apachelounge.com builds, which are the ones we recommend to use with PHP Binaries.