# Memcache not working on PHP 5.3.10

Tags: php, memcached

I Upgraded PHP 5.2.8 to php 5.3.10, but php_memcache.dll(Memcache 2.2.6 VC9 x64 Thread Safe) is not getting enabled. I have tried many link.

http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

http://shikii.net/blog/installing-memcached-for-php-5-3-on-windows-7/,

[WAMPSERVER php_memcache extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971063/wampserver-php-memcache-extension)

http://pureform.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/installing-memcache-on-windows-for-php/

Compiler version is MSVC6

and Architecture is x86.

I have php_memecache.dll in php/ext folder and in php.ini, it shows that memcached is enabled, but whenever i use, it throws the error.

```
 PHP Startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module
 Module compiled with module API=20060613
 PHP compiled with module API=20090626
 These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
```

Any idea,how can this issue be resolved?

Comment: have you installed memcached in your server?? and where you are trying your memcached in linux environment or in windows environment??

Comment: Yeah i have installed memcached. I am trying on windows environment.

Comment: in windows it is difficult, because you have installed memcached, and calling the class of memcache, instead of windows if you will try the same in linux environment, then memcached is working with memcache extension, cause linux understand memcached as memcache also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the memcache dll from this link. and it worked well with php 5.3.10.

http://fixitwizkid.com/threads/installing-memcached-for-windows-on-apache-php-and-xenforo.8905/