# fix path for phpmyadmin in wampserver

Tags: apache, configuration, phpmyadmin, alias, wampserver

Phpmyadmin was working fine but i can't remember what changes i made and now i get a 404 page not found error when I try to go `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` or `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin`. Otherwise the server is working fine. I'm running wampserver, and accessing everything locally on my own machine.

The apache error log file says this:

```
[Wed Jul 31 16:01:16 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/wamp/www/phpmyadmin, referer: http://localhost/
```

windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts file says this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

the phpmyadmin.conf alias file says this:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "D:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.3.9/" 

<Directory "D:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.3.9/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from ::1
</Directory>
```

I also went into Control panel's Event viewer and got the following detail on an event:

```
Application popup: Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic link library d:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/ext/php_memcache.dll - The specified module could not found.
```

Which is strange, but I then copied the php_memcache.dll file from a backup system and restarted the server, but still get the 404 error on phpmyadmin.

What's gone wrong? Why is phpmyadmin giving a 404 error?

### Update 1

Despite having the file in the mentioned path, I still get the above error that the php_memcache.dll is not found.

### Update 2

I've installed php_memcache.dll so that I don't get that error any more, but phpmyadmin is still not found. It *was* working fine before some change I mmade that I can't remember!

Comment: Is your WAMP icon green, and have you checked your PHP error log?

Comment: Yes the icon is green, and the PHP error log is empty.

Comment: Are you using php_memcache? You could try disabling it in your php.ini - or, have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971063/wampserver-php-memcache-extension

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and apparently I've successfully installed php_memcached now because I don't get that error in the Event viewer any more.... but phpmyadmin still gives a 404 error!

Comment: Can you post how you fixed the install, if its not too embarassing

Comment: If I remembered what I did I wouldn't have this issue :S I simply downloaded wampserver (v 2.1) and installed it and everything worked. Then I had to paste the application folder in www. I also played around with virtual hosts a bit and configuration files a bit and can't remember what it is I did that made this happen. Since then I've replaced the `apache`, `phpmyadmin`, `php` folders with a mirror working system (from where I got the application folder), to undo whatever changes I made, but it's still not working. In fact none of the aliases are working (sqlbuddy and webgrind).

Answer (score 1):

Ok if you have created Virtual Hosts have you added one so that WAMP continues to work, I suspect not, so try adding this as the FIRST vhost definition in the vhost definition file.

```
## must be the first definition so the the wamp menu page loads
##
## Remember the first vhost definition is used as the default if Apache cannot find the domain
## name enter in the browser. So this also serves as a security protection mechanism
## as long as you leave Deny from all, Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
## It will cause Apache to reject casual attempts at hacking your IP if you allow 
## other vhosts to be accessed from the big bad internet.
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@homemail.net
    DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www">
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure this is the FIRST vhost in the `D:\wamp_current\bin\apache\apache2.x.y\conf\extra\httpd-vhost.conf` file.

Comment: i just tried this. no difference. in fact, i also tried to create a random test alias using the wampserver's menu > apache > alias directories > add alias. the process went smoothly and wampserver restarted but when i checked the menu again, the alias was never added!

Comment: actually of course it wouldn't work! I hadn't uncommented the `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` directive in http.conf. However, now that I've uncommented it.... the apache service isn't starting up.

Comment: okay the reason was that there was a syntax error on this line: ` Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1`, so I removed `localhost` and `::1`. Apache now starts up but now I get a 403 Forbidden error when I try to go to `localhost/phpmyadmin`.

Comment: okay no i'm back to square 1. I put `allow from 127.0.0.1` and `allow from localhost` on two separate lines and get 404 not found again.

Comment: i gave up. i just pasted the phpmyadmin folder into /www. :S However, I would love to know what was wrong in the first place... why aliases aren't working.

Comment: I assume you changed the `D:` to whereever you had installed wamp

Comment: If you come over to www.wampserver.com and ask for help in the english forum, i can offer to teamViewer into your system and do some troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

php_memcache requires zlib to also be installed like it says on the freely available PHP web site

[php_memcache requirements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.requirements.php)

Comment: i've checked phpinfo() and zlib is enabled fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write: Include "c:/wamp/alias/*" on httpd.conf file.