# Memcache installation in Windows 8: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, memcached

I think Memcache has not been installed in windows 8. I suppose the following warning say this clearly:

```
 Notice: Memcache::get() [memcache.get]: Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211) failed with: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060) in C:\xampp\htdocs\framework\registry\cache.class.php on line 39
```

In phpinfo() I can see that it's been installed:
[image]

Is there any workaround for this to get it up and running?
In the command prompt I tried to install memcache as below:

```
memcached -d install
```

but got the following error:

```
failed to install service or service already installed
```

I've installed Memcache back in the time in windows XP.

Comment: have you tried to establish a connection on the port to see if it is  blocked by the firewall?

Comment: Installing the PHP memcache extension, doesn't automatically install a memcache server...

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 I tried to connect using: $test3 = @memcache_connect('127.0.0.1',11211); but got the mentioned error.

Comment: @Leigh when I try to install using `memcached -d install` command, I get the following message:
`failed to install service or service already installed`

Comment: Look at the answer provided by GKK - `telnet 127.0.0.1 11211` - if you dont have telnet on your box follow these instructions http://www.itworld.com/software/227783/enable-telnet-windows-8

Comment: Are you sure the service is started?  from the RUN box type `services.msc` and click start on the memcached service http://my.axerosolutions.com/Assets/Uploaded-CMS-Files/05f77d80-967d-4e4a-ac47-b5527de0a656.png

Comment: I couldn't find Memcached in the services! So when I try `memcached -d install` it's not getting installed, right?

Comment: Follow these instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016656/how-to-enable-memcache-in-wamp#10804940

Comment: I didn't work for me. I got the same error in CMD part: failed to install service or service already installed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So interesting! ;)
I ran the CMD as administrator(Run as administrator) and voila, problem solved!

Comment: i did the same but now i have to start the service only via admin CMD only

Comment: had same problem..for some days...finally solved..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below thing worked for me in windows 10.

Part 1:- Installation :- Download memcached, unzip it and put it in d:\memcache folder after (I used d drive you can use other). Open command prompt as an administrator. I ran install command `D:\memcache>memcached.exe -d install` after that, I got "failed to install service or service already installed" error. So I used `memcached.exe -vvv` command. After that it gave me lots of lines in command prompt.

Part 2:- Running :-
Now goto task manager (alt+ctrl+del) and click on Services tab, find **memcached** in name column and right click on that and click on **start**. Now you should be able to see **Running** in status of that memcached row.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you memcache daemon is accepting connection by using a `telnet` to `127.0.0.1:11211`, if you get a prompt just press enter and it should display `ERROR`.

Comment: My firewall is off and I'm still getting the same DARN error.

Comment: I got `Connect Failed` message in CMD.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 64 bit Windows 7.

When I run `memcached.exe` server starts up. I can do `telnet localhost 11211` it connects to the server. Mind this is without running cmd as administrator. Sad part is that neither the server nor the telnet prints anything.

Try typing `stats` after connecting from telnet. You should get something like

```
STAT pid 10876
STAT uptime 345
STAT time 1417453754
STAT version 1.2.6
STAT pointer_size 32
STAT curr_items 0
STAT total_items 0
STAT bytes 0
STAT curr_connections 3
STAT total_connections 5
STAT connection_structures 4
STAT cmd_get 0
STAT cmd_set 0
STAT get_hits 0
STAT get_misses 0
STAT evictions 0
STAT bytes_read 32
STAT bytes_written 21
STAT limit_maxbytes 67108864
STAT threads 1
END
```

Now comes installing it as service. This is when I get

```
C:\Users\athakur\Softwares\memcached>memcached.exe -d install
failed to install service or service already installed
```

Same goes for start and stop. **To install it as a service you will need to execute above command as Administrator.**

If no messages or notifications on server start bother you like it does for me you can start you server is verbose mode. I use

```
memcached.exe -vvv
```

which is like the highest level of verbose I guess. You can check all command with `memcached.exe -h`