# Memcached on xampp

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, memcached

Read many topics about `Memcache` and `Memcached` PHP extensions, Find related PECL packages of `Memcached` [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached/), but unfortunately I can't compile it (v2.0.1 with PHP 5.4.7)  right now.

So I downloaded compiled version from [moojiuce](http://www.moojuice.net/php-extensions) `PHP-5.4.8_memcache-2.2.7_x86_vc9.zip` a dll file which xampp doesn't display error on including it in `php.ini` as `extension=php_memcache.dll`

Besides, I also found that there should be a [memcached service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14719366/1020526) enabled on windows.

*I installed the service and respectfully the extension.*

I confused why the .dll file is named `php_memcache` and the service is `memcached`, how ever I need `Memcached` as working with laravel framework.

These are shown on `phpinfo()` about `Memcache`!:

```
memcache support                   enabled
Active persistent connections      0
Version                            2.2.7
Revision                           $Revision: 327750 $

Directive                   Local Value              Master Value
memcache.allow_failover          1                        1
memcache.chunk_size             8192                    8192
memcache.default_port           11211                   11211
memcache.default_timeout_ms     1000                    1000
memcache.hash_function          crc32                   crc32
memcache.hash_strategy          standard                standard
memcache.max_failover_attempts  20                      20
```

I get `Class 'Memcached' not found` error!

Helps are really appreciated!

Comment: `Memcache` is not `Memcached`. They are two different things, Laravel support `Memacached` only. You may write your own driver for `Memcache`...

Comment: @Andreyco yes, and I need `Memcached`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging a lot, I finally concluded there is no `Memcached` extension as a single .dll file for Windows. So Windows users may go with conventional `Memcache` or if it's possible changing server to a Linux one. However there are some PHP classes made for simulating `Memcached` for Windows.

Comment: Where can I find those classes that simulates?