# Memcached on Windows and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, memcached, wamp

When I try to use Cache in Laravel 4, I get the following error:

> Class 'Memcached' not found in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\MemcachedConnector.php

I thought that I have memcached installed, because I've been using it with another PHP application, but it seems that it is memcache (this is working fine outside of Laravel): $memcached = new Memcache;

The steps that I followed to install memcache before were similar to the steps described in the answer here: [How to enable memcache in WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016656/how-to-enable-memcache-in-wamp)

I couldn't find a way to install memcached (not memcache) on Windows. Is there any? Or, can I set some kind of dummy cache, where the cache functions will not fail on my development PC, but work on the production server without any issues?

I'm using WAMP server.

Comment: every letter counts: `new Memcache` =/= `new Memcached` - And as you didn't find a way to install memcached, in the danger I tell the obvious: You need to install it if you want to use it. So it doesn't install from alone... . Normally this is solved by googling the error message in double quotes and adding some related terms (windows, php version etc.).

Comment: Of course I tried to search for it, that's why I said that I couldn't find a way to install Memcached and that Memcache is already installed.

Comment: Well, in the end you need to install it otherwise it won't work. So now this is some kind ofdilemma. Can you imagine a way to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

At this time only on package available for laravel [LARAVEL-CASH](https://github.com/schickling/laravel-cash).

This package is contributed by some people and still in emerging state.

This package run on memcache & nginx.

COMING SOON IN PACKAGE:

```
Support for named routes
Support for rules in route group scope
More precise hierarchic invalidation
Apache support
Memcache support
Cache warmup
Individual cache rewarmup
```

Comment: Not the right place to advertise your services/sources on different question.