# php_memcache.dll for WAMP 2.5 - PHP : 5.5.12 - Window8:64 Bit - VC11

Tags: memcached, wamp, php-5.5

I am searching for php_memcache.dll and found the below links

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/

http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

I tried all of them but still it shows warning sign for the dll like below . Is any one tried and have working dll , if so could you please help me and share the one you have  ( memcache or memcached ) ? Thanks for your help .

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The warning icon means one of 2 things when seen on the extension menu.

1. There is a dll in the `ext` folder but there is no matching `extension=php_memcache.dll` entry in the `PHP.INI` file.
2. There is a `extension=xxx.dll` in the `PHP.INI` file but no matching dll in the `ext` folder.

So if you copied the dll into `\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z\ext` folder then you need to add the `extension=php_memcache.dll` to the `PHP.INI` file. Remember this is not a default extension as you needed to download it yourself, so there will be no entry in the php.ini file for it either.

**Also remember that you have to install MEMCACHED as the extension on its own is just an interface to the MEMCACHE service.**

Also you will need the Thread Safe version of the memcache.dll to run with WampServers configuration of Apache and PHP.

Also make sure you have the right 32/64bit version of memcache.dll to match the version of WAMPServer you installed.

Also remember there are 2 `php.ini` files, to edit the one used by Apache, use the wampmanager menus like so :-

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

That will launch your editor on `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\phpForApache.ini`

The other one `\wamp\bin\php\php.ini` is only used by the PHP CLI (Command Line Interface) and will have no effect on what is loaded to an Apache instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for late response . I missed out adding the entry in PHP.INI file .

Comment: Need to remember to edit the correct php.ini in: `\wamp\bin\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini`. I always edit the wrong one in the php folder

Comment: @JohnMagnolia Then use the wampmanager menu `wampmanager->PHP->php.ini` thats why its there.

Comment: The linebreaks are all messed up using notepad and I prefer to vim edit

Comment: Yea for some reason they released 2.5 with the conf files all in Unix format. Think that is back to DOS for the next release.

Comment: Oh and nobidy uses notepad, download notepad++ its free and very good and copes with DOS and UNIX line endings

Comment: @vcRobe Thanks for the edit. Dont know why I didnt see that, or the other 10+ people that must have read it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly You're welcome. I also changed to bold the MEMCACHED  sentence because memcache is not working for me because I didn't pay attention to that sentence and indeed MEMCACHED is missing in my system. Now it works! But for some reason the extension isn't showed in the PHP extensions list. So my recommendation is to check first if the cache is working before trying to see it in the list or fix something.

Comment: In case you need to install memcached here are the steps to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016656/how-to-enable-memcache-in-wamp?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how you installed it... I'm using the same version of WAMP (2.5, Windows8, 64bit, PHP 5.5.12)

I copied php_memcache.dll to C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext (default installation), and then modified C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini (also default installation) by adding

```
extension=php_memcache.dll
```

in the "Dynamic Extensions" section, restart WAMP services and it works fine. Just make sure you modified the right php.ini, it's not the one in php's directory.

BTW, I don't have php_memcache in the menu like yours as shown in the picture, but it's loaded and working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for late response . I missed out adding the entry in PHP.INI file . I think RiggsFolly responded first and so I selected his answer . Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Even i got the same issue as shown above and was struggling from 2 days, you can find  php.ini in 2 places under wamp server. enable the memcache dll extension in apache folder . i.e C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin
add the below line

**`extension=php_memcache.dll`**

. Now restart your wamp and you can see the memcache enabled.

Comment: I had an issue - "CMemCache requires PHP memcache extension to be loaded.", on Yii only with command line scripts. Solved by changing php.ini in both PHP and Apache folders. Thanks.