# Memcached is not working on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, memcached, codeigniter-2

I am trying to use the memcached for my large database queries. So far, I have installed the memcached services and it is running fine. Another thing which I am unable to find is `php_memcached.dll` file for windows 7, 64 bit. There are few but they talk about `php_memcache.dll`. I have installed that one and I can see in the `Wamp->PHP->PHP extentions` that the extension is running. Finally, I have created the `memcached.php` file in the `application/config/` directory and put the following code:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config = array(
    'default' => array(
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'port'      => 11211,
        'weight'    => 1
    )
);
?>
```

Whenever I se `phpinfo();` I am unable to locate that memcached is configured. 
I do not know where I am going wrong. I reckon this is because I have installed `memcached` service and `php_memcache.dll` extension. Is this could be the reason ??

Or what could be potentially reason that it is not working on codeigniter.?

Comment: You might find all the info needed in here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016656/how-to-enable-memcache-in-wamp
Seems that it requires some step to install it on 64 bit windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

codeigniter is trying to load the php memcached extension which is most likely not the one that comes with your windows installation. You will need to modify cached_memcached.php file located in the libraries folder.

and find this line

```
$this->memcached = new Memcached();
```

replace it with

```
 $this->memcached = new Memcache();
```

you can also choose to install the php memcached extension through pecl