# Symfony PHP 5.5 : ErrorException: Notice: Memcache::connect(): failed

Tags: php, symfony, winapi, memcached, wamp

I am getting error while configuring `Memcache` with `Symfony`. Can anyone suggest on this. I have installed `Memcache` on `wamp` server using `PHP 5.5`

```
ErrorException: Notice: Memcache::connect(): Server localhost (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
(10060)
```

Comment: for install  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016656/how-to-enable-memcache-in-wamp . it is surely a installation problem, or open / close port

Comment: @MouradK : I have ran phpinfo and it shows enabled

Comment: but does your memcache service is run ?  (the dll does not tell us anything about this)

Comment: I tried to run .exe file, somehow it is not working due to MSVC11 compiler version and using php5.5

Comment: To use Memcache in PHP you have to install a Memcache server. It can be [downloaded from here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/)

Comment: You can download and install the MSVC runtime for [MSVC11 (VC2012) from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

Answer (score 0):

Your memcached server is not running. You need to start it.

If you're running Ubuntu, it's as simple as `sudo service memcached start`. For other operating systems, you may want to consult the manual. If you are having problems getting memcached set up, go to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) and ask for help there.

Comment: Tagged as WAMP so he is using windows! I expect he has not actually installed a Memcache server.

Comment: @RiggsFolly:  Memcache is already installed and I am able to see in my phpinfo.

Comment: That's not how Memcached works. You may have the PHP extension enabled, but that is not Memcached. You must have the actual Memcached server software running. To reiterate that, the extension being there, is in *not way whatsoever* an indication that a Memcached server is running, or even accessible from PHP.