# Yii2 - can't use cache component to save objects with expiration duration to memcached

Tags: php, memcached, yii2

I have an application that uses php with Yii2 as its REST API backend.
I code on a machine running `Windows 8 64bit and WAMP 2.5 with a local instance of memcached` and test on an `Amazon EC2 instance running ubuntu that uses Amazon ElastiCache and running apache2`.

I found that using the built-in Yii2 cache component does not allow me to set or add objects to cache with an expiration duration on either installation BUT that if I use the PHP extension directly it works like a charm.

Code example:

```
$cacheObject = Yii::$app->cache;

$cacheObject->add('testKey','testValue',10);

if($cacheObject->add('testKey','testValue',10))
{
    return 'Something is wrong with Yii2 cache component!';
}
else
{
    return 'Timed caching with Yii2 works!';
}
// Above code never enters else clause.


$memcachedObject = new Memcached();
$memcachedObject->addServer(CACHE_ENDPOINT,CACHE_PORT);

$memcachedObject->add('testKey2','testValue2',10);

if($memcachedObject->add('testKey2','testValue2',10))
{
    return 'Something is wrong with memcached extension';
}
else
{
    return 'Timed caching with Memcached extension works!';
}
// This code always enters else clause.
```

I doubt there's something I have to do to enable timed caching in Yii2.

For reference, I used the instructions from the answer to this question in order to install and run my local memcached instance - [How to enable memcache in WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016656/how-to-enable-memcache-in-wamp) but seeing as it also happens on my EC2 instance I doubt there's a problem with my installation.

Any ideas on why this does not work?

Comment: Can you post your yii main config? May be you miss something there.

Answer (score 0):

As you know PHP implements memcached (the server) integration with 2 different libraries:

- memcache ([PHP memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php))
- memcached ([PHP memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php))

Yii2 instead expose only one interface using **useMemcached** attribute in **MemCache** class.

See the code from **MemCache** class:

```
protected function addValue($key, $value, $duration)
{
    $expire = $duration > 0 ? $duration + time() : 0;
    return $this->useMemcached ? $this->_cache->add($key, $value, $expire) : $this->_cache->add($key, $value, 0, $expire);
}
```

I think there's a mismatch *between* your php-libs of memcache/memcached (see **phpinfo()** ) *and* your Yii2 config (see **useMemcached** attribute - default is **false**).

Comment: I've already checked that and there's no mismatch.  
I'm thinking it might be a clock problem, seeing as Yii2 always converts the duration to unix time, but I'm unsure about it because I wouldn't expect it to happen on a local instance of memcached as the memcached instance and the app server (apache) are on the same machine and thus should share the same clock.