# Memcached not found in wamp windows 8

Tags: php, caching, memcached

i am trying to install Memcached on windows 8 and Wamp.

i followed the guidance from [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016656/how-to-enable-memcache-in-wamp)

i.e:

```
Copy MSVCP71.DLL, msvcr71.dll to C:\windows\sysWOW64
Copy memcached.exe into C:\memcached
Click Windows-Key
Type: CMD
press: Ctrl-Shift-Enter
Choose yes
type: C:\memcached\memcached.exe -d install
type: C:\memcached\memcached.exe -d start
Copy php_memcache.dll to C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\ext
    Restart Apache using Wamp controls
    Enable WAMP -> PHP -> PHP Extensios -> php_memcache
```

however, when i try to call the class from within my Zend 2 module i get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found in

i tried calling it like this:

```
$memcache = new \Memcached(); 
$memcache->addServer('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

i also tried calling it like this:

```
define('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('MEMCACHED_PORT', '11211');

// Connection creation
$memcache = new \Memcache;
$cacheAvailable = $memcache->connect(MEMCACHED_HOST, MEMCACHED_PORT);
```

in my **php ini** file i did as follows:

```
extension=c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\php_memcache.dll
```

i also went to my

Enable WAMP -> PHP -> PHP Extensios -> php_memcache

and enabled Memcache

however, i did notice that i could not find any reference to memcache in my php info

**UPDATE**

FOLLOWING the advice from this [article](http://shiki.me/blog/installing-memcached-for-php-5-3-on-windows-7/)

i ran the following test from my command line to see if the Memcached server is working:

```
wmic process get description, executablepath | findstr memcached.exe
```

it returned the correct path to teh file (which means its running correctly)

so, the problem is with the PHP file.

i have tried putting this as the full path:

extension=c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\php_memcache.dll

or simply as this:

extension=php_memcache.dll

but to no avail