# WAMP Failed to initialize storage module: memcache (path: c:/wamp/tmp)

Tags: memcached, wamp, handler

i am trying to make wamp to save sessions on memcache however, after all installations and troubleshooting i still get below errors:
 1) when i have php.ini with this (session.save_handler = memcache) i got below error:

> Failed to initialize storage module: memcache (path: c:/wamp/tmp)

2) when i have php.ini with this (session.save_handler = memcache**d**) i got below error:

```
Cannot find save handler 'memcached'
```

Comment: You have I assume installed memcache?

Comment: yes, i installed memcache and put dll in the relative document. I also confirmed that memcache is working with no issue. however when I change session.save_handler in php.ini to memcache or memchached then i got above mentioned errors

Comment: Did you start the MEMCACHED Service?

Comment: right, memchached is started and i can read and write values to it.

Comment: i followed this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016656/how-to-enable-memcache-in-wamp

Comment: Hopefully not the answer with a tick as that is at best _way out of date_ and the links are to very old MEMCACHE

Comment: well, thats the only one i could find for windows WAMP. Do you know a better one?

Comment: This looks promising https://commaster.net/content/installing-memcached-windows

Comment: thanks very much, i actually found that is the version i installed too.