# Can't get memcached to work in Windows

Tags: windows, memcached

I have installed and started `memcached 1.4.4.14` as a service in Windows 7 and it turns up among the services in the Task manager. I use WAMP for web developing, so I also downloaded the `3.0.8. DLL binary (php_memcache.dll)` and put it in this folder: `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.15\ext`. To complete I added the row `extension=php_memcache.dll` in the php.ini file in WAMP. After all this I also restarted the computer.

Then when I test the memcached service with phpinfo(), it's not listed.

Also when I point my browser to a php file with this snippet:

```
$memcache = new Memcache();
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211);

if ($memcache === FALSE){
    echo 'Unable to connect to memcache';
}
```

... I get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in C:\wamp\www\memcached_test.php on line 3
```

Can anyone see where I went the wrong way? There is an old post that seems to be a duplicate to this one, but the answers to that post did not help me.

EDITED: I should also mention that I have now tried the 1.2.6-win32-bin version. I can install, start and stop the service. But the fun ends there. No connection with WAMP.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved thanks [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016656/how-to-enable-memcache-in-wamp)

My problem was that although my Windows installation is 64 bits my WAMP version is 32 bit. So all I had to do was to download and install the 32 bit DLL (the x86 TS version) from [this location](https://pecl.php.net/package/memcache/3.0.8/windows) to get WAMP to play ball with memcached.

Comment: can you tell us where did you get memcached service for windows ?